# $I_A \circ R = R \circ I_B = R$ where $I_A = \{ (a,a) | a \in A \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $R$ be a subset of $A\times B$. Prove that $I(A) \circ R = R \circ I(B) = R$, where $I(A) = \{(a,a)| a \in A\}$ .

Comment: Proving it should be easy once you understand how to compose relations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I have read this site. But I couldn't prove :(

Comment: @Omnomnomnom this is my answer
(x,y) ∈ I(A)oR 
then there is a z : (x,z)∈I(A) and (z,y)∈R
by the definition of I(A) : x = z and we have (x,x)∈I(A) and (x,y)∈R 
I don't have any thing to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just definitions:

Let $(x,y) \in I(A) \circ R$. This means by definition that there is some $z \in A$ such that $(x,z) \in I(A)$ and $(z,y) \in R$.

But $(x,z) \in I(A)$ means that actually by necessity $z=x$ and so the second fact gives us $(x,y) = (z,y) \in R$. So $I(A) \circ R  \subseteq R$

The proof that $R \circ I(B) \subseteq R$ is similar.

The reverse inclusions are also obvious: if $(x,y) \in R$ we can take $z=x$ to note that the pairs $(x,x) \in I(A), (x,y)\in R$ show that $(x,y) \in I(A) \circ R$ and similarly for the $I(B)$ case again.

Comment: In the last section : why we can take x = z?

Comment: @Yahya we take $z=x$ ($z$  is the "connecting element" in the composition)